# What does "peg" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Amplification also pegs the responsibility for technology’s impact squarely on us.

Comment: Have a look at the meaning at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peg). Especially 1C, 2B, and 3B.

Answer (score 2):

*Blame, pin upon, hold accountable*

These are the nearest meanings.

Note: Finding many examples of this usage on the web but not authentic source as yet, still looking, will edit as soon as I find one.)

> It pegs the responsibility entirely on some vague and nebulous “them”.
>
> The new status of the case, in effect, pegs the responsibility for commissioning the crime on a single culprit.

Answer (score 1):

It means 'affixes' or 'attaches' or 'fastens' or 'pins'. So, 'Amplification also **fastens** the responsibility for technology’s impact squarely on us.'

Several of the definitions I found online for 'peg' included a verb definition something like 'to fasten or attach with pegs', but didn't include the idea that the peg itself might be metaphorical rather than literal. However, [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/peg) has a simple 'To affix or pin' definition, and definition #12 on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peg) has 'to fasten with or as with pegs' - of which this is the second option: 'to fasten *as with* pegs'.